# Modern Filesystems and Small Files?

Tags: filesystems

Do modern file systems, such as ext4, ntfs, and apfs, always start files in a new sector, or may some files share the space in the same sector?

Answer (score 1):

`btrfs` appears to be the most widely-used filesystem that uses block suballocation

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_suballocation